How can I run a specific model (e.g., Nvidia Hymba 1.5B) with Open Web UI?
I’m trying to run the Hymba 1.5 model using Open Web UI, but I’m not entirely sure how to configure everything correctly. I have the model downloaded, and I’ve set up the Open Web UI environment. Here’s what I’ve done so far:


Installed Python and all dependencies for Open Web UI.
Cloned the Open Web UI repository.
Downloaded the Hymba 1.5 model (please let me know if it’s available on Hugging Face or another platform).


I’m unclear on:

•   Where exactly to place the model files.     •   How to configure Open
Web UI to recognize and load this model.  •   Any additional steps to
optimize the setup (e.g., GPU acceleration, quantization).

Could someone provide step-by-step guidance or point me to relevant resources?
